# Send an array of data to a function without using serialize

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, arraylist

I have an array that loaded data from excel, now I need to send this data to another view for a review of test, but this not found because is a array in a function, I try to use serialize and unserialize but this send a error of limit of characteres in the url.

```
public function excel() {
    $this->loadModel('SoyaProductorCompra');
    $excel=array();
    $k=0;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $datos = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
        $datos->read($this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['excel']['tmp_name']);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $datos->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
            $excel[$k]['producto']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
            $excel[$k]['toneladas']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];
            $excel[$k]['precio']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
            $excel[$k]['total']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
            $excel[$k]['fecha']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5];
            $excel[$k]['id']=$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][6];
            $k++;

        }
        $this->set('excels',$excel);

        //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'revision', serialize($excel))); not found
    }
}
```

this is my other function that recive the array and show in my view but not found

```
public function revicionexcel($data) {
    //$data=unserialize($data);  not work
    //debug($data); not work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't send the data of a whole spreadsheet through a query string regardless, even if it were small enough to do that.  I mean, what would happen if someone started manually editing the URL for instance?  Either write the data to a file, or save it in the session instead.

Comment: you're right, but I need the data from excel, I do not need the file. It is for this reason that I need to save the data stored in an array and send for review and editing. I am see options for do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're calling the funciton inside the same controller, right?

If so, then why you just don't use:

```
public function excel()
{
    //read excel into $excel variable
    $this->revicionexcel($excel);
}
```

so, no need of redirects here

Although it's recommended that you have the excel reading in the `model layer`, as this layer is intended for all kind of data management.

### Edit:

Then, based on your comments, you can move all the reading to the model, and call it from the controller:

### *SoyaProductorCompra* model:

```
public function excel($data) {
    //your excel reading function as you have it on the controller.
    //change all "$this->request->data" references for the parameter "$data"
    //be sure to return the excel properly.
    ...
    return $excel;
}
```

### *SoyaProductorCompras* controller:

```
public function revision()
{
    $excel = $this->SoyaProductorCompra->excel($this->request->data);
    $this->set('excels', $excel);
}
```

What we're doing here is to call the excel opening in the model from the action `revision()`, and sending them to its view. You don't need to redirect here.

Comment: yes but how i can redirect to revicionexcel with my array

Comment: But, is there any reason to use redirect instead of normal method call?

Comment: yes because need work wirt these data before to save, for do this need show the data and edit or delete some data.